# $ini =& eZINI::instance();

Tags: operators

I have just come across this in a few files within an eZ framework:

```
$ini =& eZINI::instance();
```

What exactly does the =& do. I've never seen it before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this thread is old, but i stumbled upon it while searching for the reference for the eZINI class so i might as well answer your question.

`$a =& $b` assigns `$b`'s reference to `$a`. This essentially means that `$a` and `$b` will be aliases for the same memory location. Thus manipulating `$a` will manipulate `$b` as well and vice-versa.